# Python: Automatic object generation plus naming

Tags: python, class, object, automation, increment

We have a class with some mathematical functions inside

```
class MyObjects(object):
    q=1      #could be any number
    def f(x,y):
        return q*y+x    #could be any mathematical function
```

Let's say we want to create 100 new objects named like `object_1` , `object_2`...`object_100`  of this class and all of them must have a variable `q` defined, but defined for each object as `q_1` , `q_2` ... `q_100` but we want every time an object is created to increment the value of q like `if q=1: 
q_1=q+1
q_2=q_1+1` and so on. As displayed previously all objects must use the f(x,y) function of the class named for each object like `f_1` , `f_2` ... `f_100` . the number of objects generated is going to be set by the user with `input()` and that is the reason i would like to automate this procedure which is very cumbersome to do "by hand" by adding that is something like a hundred objects in the code. So can i automate this procedure? Python begginer, monty python veteran lol. Feel free to edit the question if you can rephrase it in a more precise manner.

Comment: Your use-case is hypothetical, but as-stated it sounds like  you'd be better off using dicts to map to these things rather than actual objects.

Comment: I'm confused about the relation between `f(x,y)` and the variable `q` (or `q_1` ...).  Can you please try to explain that a little better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a class attribute `q` and an instance attribue `q`.
And every time a new instance is created the `MyObjects.q` will be incremented and that incremented value will be assigned to `self.q`

```
class MyObjects(object):
    q=0
    def __init__(self):
       MyObjects.q+=1
       self.q=MyObjects.q

    def f(self,x,y):
        return self.q*y+x
inp=input("Enter number of objects: ")
dic={}
for x in range(1,inp+1):
    dic[x]=MyObjects()
```

**output:**

```
>>> dic[1].q
1
>>> dic[2].q
2
>>> dic[3].q
3
>>> dic[1].f(2,5)
7
>>> dic[2].f(2,5)
12
>>> dic[3].f(2,5)
17
```

Comment: Yep, this is how you do it.  You could demonstrate using the method `f` if you want to complete the example, but it should be pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: This is nice! But how can we automate this: if we ask the user something like "how many objects would you like to create?" and take an answer: user_input=input("Enter number of objects: ") and the user sets: user_input=100, how can we create automatically that many objects (without having to write anything else)

Comment: @user1513300 you can use `range()` and dictionary to automate, see my updated answer.

Comment: inp=int(input("Enter number of objects: ")) if using python3.10.6, 
inputs are strings and you need an int for iterating.

Comment: or, of course,  do the int conversion later....
for x in range(1,int(inp)+1)